# PHP: Cant call a onclick function inside an echo

Tags: php

What can i do so i can call the onclick funtion?? really need help, thanks beforehand :)

```
  if ($result1 = mysqli_query($con, $SQL1)){

    while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
      echo "
    <h1>$row1[Navn]</h1>
    <hr>
    <div id='Billedinfo'>
      <div id='Billed'>
        <div id='Hoved'>
          <img id='billedet' src='Billeder/$row1[Billed]'>
        </div>
        <div id='Billederne'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo1' src='Billeder/$row1[billed1]'onmouseover='hover('photo1')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo1')' onclick='chooser('photo1')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo2' src='Billeder/$row1[billed2]' onmouseover='hover('photo2')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo2')' onclick='chooser('photo2')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo3' src='Billeder/$row1[billed3]' onmouseover='hover('photo3')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo3')' onclick='chooser('photo3')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo4' src='Billeder/$row1[billed4]' onmouseover='hover('photo4')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo4')' onclick='chooser('photo4')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo5' src='Billeder/$row1[billed5]' onmouseover='hover('photo5')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo5')' onclick='chooser('photo5')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo6' src='Billeder/$row1[billed6]' onmouseover='hover('photo6')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo6')' onclick='chooser('photo6')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo7' src='Billeder/$row1[billed7]' onmouseover='hover('photo7')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo7')' onclick='chooser('photo7')'>
          <img class='Andrebilleder' id='photo8' src='Billeder/$row1[billed8]' onmouseover='hover('photo8')' onmouseout='hoverout('photo8')' onclick='chooser('photo8')'>
        </div>
```

Comment: Put that inside in the DOM ready function.

Comment: change `onclick='chooser('photo1')'` to `onclick=\"chooser('photo1')\"`

Answer (score 1):

Also you have error in inserting php variables.

Replace $row1[Navn] to $row1['Navn'] and same for all php variables.

And call js function like this,

```
 onmouseout=\"hoverout('photo8')\"
```

Comment: Not really, that part works fine, i get the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the generated HTML which is **very** messed up because you include quotes inside other quotes without any consideration.

To include a quote inside another set of the same quote, you need to escape it with a `\`.

`onmouseover='hover('photo6')'` would become `onmouseover='hover(\'photo6\')'`

You should also get PHP warnings considering that you refer to array indices as constants instead of strings (`$row1[billed8]` which should be `$row1['billed8']`).